# jquery styling content in dynamic element

Tags: php, jquery, css, flexslider

I am using the jquery plugin flexslider to display some images and captions. I am using the code below to take captions out of the flexslider content and place into an outside element.

The captions are styled using spans but when they are placed into the new element called ".captions" they are not styled and all text is running together.

How can I apply styling and formatting to the text in the ".captions" div?

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(window).load(function() {

    $captions = $('.captions');

    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "fade",
        controlNav: "thumbnails",
        directionNav: true,
        slideshow: false,
        useCSS: true,
        touch: true,
        start: function() {
            $activecaption = $('.flex-active-slide .flex-caption');
            $captions.html($activecaption.text());        
        },
        after: function() {
            $activecaption = $('.flex-active-slide .flex-caption');
            $captions.html($activecaption.text());
        }
    }); 
    });
</script>
```

For example I am echoing out this:

```
echo "<span class='artwork-title'>$page->title</span>,<span class='artwork-year'>     $artwork->date</span><span class='artwork-year'>$artwork->dimensions</span>";
```

and my jquery seems to be getting rid of the span tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After rereading the question, it seems like you need the active caption in the `.captions` element.  All you have to do is switch `.text()` to `.html()` and all of the elements should come with it.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $captions = $('.captions');

    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "fade",
        controlNav: "thumbnails",
        directionNav: true,
        slideshow: false,
        useCSS: true,
        touch: true,
        start: function() {
            $activecaption = $('.flex-active-slide .flex-caption');
            $captions.html($activecaption.html());        
        },
        after: function() {
            $activecaption = $('.flex-active-slide .flex-caption');
            $captions.html($activecaption.html());
        }
    }); 
});
```

Reference: http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Comment: Visually this is what is happening I am getting just this: <p class="captions">"Evanfall, 201236" x 54"Oil painting on acid-etched and mirrored glass"</p>

Comment: And what are you expecting inside the `<p>` tag?

Comment: I'm expecting something like this: <p class="captions"><span class="one">hello text one</span><span class="two">yep text number two</span></p> and with more spans inside the p tag.

Comment: Updated answer based on comment specifications

Comment: Ok after rereading, do you need only the active caption moved to the `.captions` element, or all of them?

Comment: No the active caption moved the captions element so I'm assuming that it would be this: $.each($(".flex-active-slide .flex-caption"), function(i, caption){ 
                //creates a span object, adds a custom class to each item, and includes the text
                $captions.append($("<span>").addClass("span-" + i).text(caption.text()));
            });
BUT right now nothing is being returned into the captions element, even with your updated code.

Comment: Tedski, thanks that works!! So to learn from this is that this:             $captions.html($activecaption.html()); returns all of the html elements and .text just returns text. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct! Sorry for how long that took

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a css class with the .addClass

```
<style>
    .capStyle
    {
        color: red;
    }
</style>

$(".captions").addClass("capStyle");
```

Comment: Yes. I could do that but what I need is to be style individual spans within the .captions div and also to put each span on a new line.